# How to make large .chm file?

Tags: filesystems, chm

My HTML pages are up to 500MB and with images up to 2GB.

I tried the MS' HTML Help Workshop, but its generated chm file is up to only 60MB size.

I also tried KEL chm Creator, chmProcessor and others, and got no luck.

This is the HTML Help Workshop's error message:

> There is not enough memory available for this task...

[image: error message]

Am I wrong with HTML Help Workshop?
Is there other way to pack HTML pages and its images into one file?

Comment: Why would you have images up to 2GB in a CHM? It sounds likely that you're using the wrong format for what you're trying to create. What would be the actual content/your goal?

Answer (score 2):

60 MB CHM file - really a big one. You should split your help file into some files with a resulting file size of < 25 MB. Remember, HTMLHelp (CHM's) is nearly 20 years old and Microsoft's Windows based help system is in "maintenance mode" only.

Please try to compile without 'Index' and /or try to reduce the number of topics to less than 1000.

Try to reduce the size of your images before compiling.

Please have a look for further information at following link and read all answers:
[File-size limits for CHM (HTML Help format) files?](https://superuser.com/questions/330418/file-size-limits-for-chm-html-help-format-files)

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34784520/1981088 too.

For your target file format CHM all tools I know are using the HH Workshop compiler.

A utility like FAR HTML can [compress and remove dead space](http://www.helpware.net/FAR/help/dlg_examine.htm#Compress_Chm) in a .chm and reduce the .chm file size (but that will only yield 10%).